# Recursive binary search on a sorted array of Strings

Tags: java, binary-search

I made an array that is 10 in length. Each slot has a name. My goal is to randomly pick a name and do a binary search to find it. I don't understand what is wrong with it but if you could at least give me a hint it would be very helpful, thank you. 
Here's my code:

```
    private int iRecursiveCalls = 0;

    public void runRecursiveTest(){

        String[] iArraySize = new String[10];

        String[] aiNumbers = new String[iArraySize.length];

        SecureRandom oRand = new SecureRandom();

        iArraySize[0] = "John";
        iArraySize[1] = "Max";
        iArraySize[2] = "Kyle";
        iArraySize[3] = "Sam";
        iArraySize[4] = "Robert";
        iArraySize[5] = "Alex";
        iArraySize[6] = "Bob";
        iArraySize[7] = "Daniel";
        iArraySize[8] = "Felix";
        iArraySize[9] = "Michael";

        String iTarget = aiNumbers[oRand.nextInt(iArraySize.length)];

        Arrays.sort(aiNumbers);

        System.out.println("Target num: " + iTarget);

        System.out.println("--- Begin Binary Search ---");
        long lBegTime = System.nanoTime();
        findNumbersBinarySearch(aiNumbers, iTarget, 0, iArraySize.length -1);
        long lEndTime = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("Elapsed time: " + (lEndTime - lBegTime));
        System.out.println("Recursive calls: " + iRecursiveCalls);
        System.out.println("--- End Binary Search ---");
    }

    private int findNumbersBinarySearch(String[] aiNumbers, String iTarget,
                                        int iLow, int iHigh){

        iRecursiveCalls++;

        int iMiddle = (iHigh + iLow) / 2;

        if(iTarget.equals(aiNumbers[iMiddle])){
            return iMiddle;
        }
        else if(iTarget.compareTo(aiNumbers[iMiddle])>0){

            return findNumbersBinarySearch(aiNumbers, iTarget,
                    iMiddle + 1, iHigh);
        }
        else{
            return findNumbersBinarySearch(aiNumbers, iTarget,
                    iLow, iMiddle - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

**What can I do to fix it?**

Comment: Welcome to SO! Do you have a base case? How does your recursion know when to stop?

Comment: Please format the code with the code formatter option.

Comment: when it finds the word

Comment: Sure, but what if it doesn't find the word?

Comment: it will because iTarget chooses a random word

Comment: then it does binary search for that word from the array of Strings

Comment: I don't see why you wouldn't want to handle that, but OK. Beyond that, you're sorting and indexing into an empty array in the caller.

Comment: What do you mean? Sorry I'm kinda still new to coding.

Comment: why did you corrupt your question?

Comment: @ScaryWombat that's not "corrupt", that's called "vandalize" (vandalism)

Comment: @iBug Thanks, words are coming to me slowly today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm isn't working because you're indexing into, sorting and passing into your function an empty array. You may have been confused between `iArraySize` and `aiNumbers`; both of these are misleading variable names because you're adding string names to `iArraySize` and `aiNumbers` doesn't contain numbers. Your binary search function name and other variables are similarly misleading; they use the word `Numbers` and the [prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation#Disadvantages) `i` even though the function header takes a `String[]` array.

Furthermore, your code will blow the call stack if the target isn't found in the array. The classic binary search will return failure once `lo > hi`; I can't think of any reason not to include the [base case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_case_(recursion)).

Another binary search gotcha is to use the formula `mid = (hi - lo) / 2 + lo`. This avoids nasty integer overflow bugs that might occur if `hi + lo > Integer.MAX_SIZE`.

This code fixes these issues by sticking to one array the whole way through, uses more accurate variable names and won't overflow the stack:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

class Main {
    private static int recursiveCalls = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        runRecursiveTest();
    }

    public static void runRecursiveTest() {
        SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();
        String[] names = {
            "John",
            "Max",
            "Kyle",
            "Sam",
            "Robert",
            "Alex",
            "Bob",
            "Daniel",
            "Felix",
            "Michael"
        };

        String target = names[rand.nextInt(names.length)];
        Arrays.sort(names);

        System.out.println("Target string: " + target);
        System.out.println("--- Begin Binary Search ---");

        long begin = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println(bisect(names, target, 0, names.length - 1));
        long end = System.nanoTime();

        System.out.println("Elapsed time: " + (end - begin));
        System.out.println("Recursive calls: " + recursiveCalls);
        System.out.println("--- End Binary Search ---");
    }

    private static int bisect(String[] arr, String target, int lo, int hi) {
        recursiveCalls++;

        if (lo > hi) { return -1; }

        int mid = (hi - lo) / 2 + lo;

        if (target.equals(arr[mid])) {
            return mid;
        }
        else if (target.compareTo(arr[mid]) > 0) {
            return bisect(arr, target, mid + 1, hi);
        }

        return bisect(arr, target, lo, mid - 1);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Target string: Sam
--- Begin Binary Search ---
9
Elapsed time: 81385
Recursive calls: 4
--- End Binary Search ---
```

[Try it!](https://repl.it/repls/MajesticGummyGuiltware)

Comment: I see, thank you a lot. I will still have to practice but this helps a lot I appreciate it.